# How to modify video using webrtc on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, webrtc

how to modify video frames before sending out with webrtc on iOS? The libjingle_peerconnection does not provide any interface to support modifying video or use custom video captures.

Comment: This question is too broad in its current form, SO is not meant to just provide you with code for a request you have. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and revise your question to offer people a better starting point for answers. Like mentioned there, including code you already have is a good idea. Point out where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The webrtc does support custom interface where you can make these modifications. You will have to add your changes to webrtc code and it does not expose APIs for this custom implementation. You can modify this code https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/modules/video_capture/objc/ to add your changes to modify video frames and rebuild libjingle.